# How to efficiently use the paste registers?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, statusline

I often don't remember what was copied lately. So I don't know if I need to  do  `<C-r>0` or `<C-R>1` in insert mode.

I tend to rely only on the `*` register, or type `:reg`, look at everything and then decide.

This is cumbersome.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some mappings to know what inside each register.

`ctrl_q+REG` for insert mode. 'R+REG' for other modes. Displays the content of register REG. For example, `R0` - displays register 0 content.

Replaced the not so useful R.

This function maps all registers so that we know what we have in each.

```
nnoremap <leader>R R
func! MapR()
    let lst=['+','*']
    for i in range(10)
        call add(lst,string(i))
    endfor
    let k=char2nr('a')
    for j in range(26)
        call add(lst,nr2char(k+j))
    endfor 
    echo lst
for i in lst 
        exec 'nmap R'. i .' :echo getreg("'.i .'")<CR>'
        exec 'vmap R'. i .' <CMD>:echo getreg("'.i .'")<CR>'
        exec 'imap <c-q>'. i .' <CMD>:echo getreg("'.i .'")<CR>'
endfor 
endf

call MapR()
```

Answer (score 0):

I arranged that when I press `<C-L>` it toggles yank mode, in which the usual status line turns into a line displaying the yank regs. 
I use Airline.

```
function! GetLine(timer)
    if !exists('g:reg_tog')
        return 
    endif
    if g:reg_tog==0 
        return
    endif 
    if (getreg('0')==getreg('*'))
        let regs=['+','1','2','3','x','z','4','5']
    else
        let regs=['*','0','1','2','x','z','4','5']
    endif 

    let tot=0
    let wid=winwidth(0)
    let s=""
    let tl=0
    let avg=0

    let countmore=0
    let lenlessthan=0
    let lenmore=0

    for it in regs
        let t=printf('%s',getreg(it))
        let t=substitute(t,"\<NL>","^M","g")
        let t=substitute(t,"\t","    ","g")
        let l= len(t) 

        if l<(wid-25)/(len(regs)+1)
            let lenlessthan+=l
        else
            let lenmore+=l 
            let countmore+=1
        endif 
    endfor 

    let neededavg = ((wid-25-(3*countmore)) - lenlessthan + 0.01) / (countmore+ 0.01)



    for it in regs
        let t=printf('%s',getreg(it))
        let t=substitute(t,"\<NL>","","g")
        let t=substitute(t,"\t","    ","g")
        let l= len(t) 
        if  l>=(wid-25)/(len(regs)+1) 
            let ll=min([len(t),float2nr(floor(neededavg))])
        else
            let ll=len(t)
        endif 
        if ll>0
            if (len(s)+ll<wid-25)
                if ll<l
                    let s=s . printf('%s',it) . ': ' . t[0:ll] .'..| '
                else
                    let s=s . printf('%s',it) . ': ' . t[0:ll] .' | '
                endif 
            endif
        endif
    endfor
    let g:line=s
endfunction

function! RegsToggle()
    if !exists('g:reg_tog')
        let g:reg_tog=0
    endif


    let g:reg_tog=!(g:reg_tog)
    if g:reg_tog
        let g:airline_section_a_temp= g:airline_section_a
        let g:airline_section_a=""
        let g:airline_section_x_temp= g:airline_section_x
        let g:airline_section_x=""
        let g:airline_section_y_temp= g:airline_section_y
        let g:airline_section_y=""
        let g:airline_section_z_temp= g:airline_section_z
        let g:airline_section_z=""
        let g:airline_section_c= "%{g:line}"
        "*=  %-0.40{printf('%s',getreg('*'))}  0=  %-0.40{printf('%s',getreg(0))}  1= %-0.40{printf('%s',getreg(1))}  2= %-0.40{printf('%s',getreg(2))} 3= %-0.40{printf('%s',getreg(3))} x= %-0.40{printf('%s',getreg('x'))}"
        let g:airline_section_error_temp= g:airline_section_error
        let g:airline_section_error=""
        let g:airline_section_warning_temp= g:airline_section_warning
        let g:airline_section_warning=""
    else
        let g:airline_section_error= g:airline_section_error_temp
        let g:airline_section_warning = g:airline_section_warning_temp
        let g:airline_section_a= g:airline_section_a_temp
        let g:airline_section_x= g:airline_section_x_temp
        let g:airline_section_y= g:airline_section_y_temp
        let g:airline_section_z= g:airline_section_z_temp
        let g:airline_section_c= '%<%{tabpagenr()} %<%{getcwd()} | %f%m %#__accent_red#%{airline#util#wrap(airline#parts#readonly(),0)}%#__restore__#'
    endif
    :AirlineRefresh
    "call airline#extensions#tabline#buflist#invalidate()
    ":redraw!
endfunction


let g:autoreg=timer_start(2000,'GetLine',{'repeat':-1})
```

and added

```
nnoremap <C-L> :call RegsToggle()<CR>
```

Notice that added timer. 
Notice that my c part is different in the usual display since it contains the current working directory.

so you can add

```
let g:airline_section_c= '%<%{getcwd()} | %f%m %#__accent_red#%{airline#util#wrap(airline#parts#readonly(),0)}%#__restore__#'
```